# Run PyOpenCl on android device

Tags: android, opencl, pyopencl

Does anyone have experience running PyOpenCl on Android Device through an Application or any other way? I can't seem to find any leads to begin with.

The specifications of my device are as follows:

ANDROID OS VERSION : 9
CPU ABI : arm64-v8a
CPU ABI 2 : armeabi-v7a

It's a Qualcomm Snapdragon 855

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should ask your query here - https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Chaquopy is definitely the way to use Python on Android. However I have not gotten into using precisely because of this problem. I do not think it will give you any GPU support, OpenCL or otherwise. If I were wrong I might consider using it as well with PyOpenCL.

Answer (score 0):

So I took a look at the current state of OpenCL on Android.

The last published metric that I found was from the Twitter team in mid 2018 for an ACM conference/publication: [Analysis of OpenCL Support for Mobile GPUs on Android](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3204919.3207893)

At the time they took a sampling of devices at the end of 2017. They found that 2/3rd of the devices had OpenCL. The authors then go into detail about Local vs Global memory for performance and provided an interesting breakdown of supported OpenCL APIs. See tables from paper below.

[image: Local memory type used by manufacturer]

[image: OpenCL versions supported by GPU models]

Now realize that OpenCL isn't officially supported by the Android framework and may even be used by other parts of the system (Renderscript, manufacturer's camera, etc.) so your experience may vary depending on context.

Back to your primary question.

You have a few possible paths:

1) If you want to run a Python environment on Android, look at [Termux](https://termux.com/) which has [some level of Python support](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Instructions_for_installing_python_packages) although you can try to install `pyopencl` via `pip` when I tried it, I got an error. I believe the error is from partially the build environment, and partially not knowing/having the correct [OpenCL driver](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html).

2) Transform your code from Python to ARM64 via [Pypy](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2019/07/pypy-jit-for-aarch64.html). How well it would support OpenCL code even with a driver, I don't know.

Other options are variations on the later, either building an Android app which calls via JNI/Android NDK into the ARM code compiled from Python. Or have it run within the Termux environment.

Depending on your application, porting/migration may be easier with a commercial license product like [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) which appear to have a free-tier for open-source projects.